# How to replace "emailRecipients" key value from a json object in java

Tags: java, json

I need to replace `emailRecipients` value with some other value.

Here is JSON

```
{"payload": {"injectedDetails": "{\"injectedDetails\":\"test\"}","originalPayload": "{\"messageId\":\"232342",
\"emailRecipients\":[\"test@abc.com\"]}"},
    "status": "OK"
}
```

I Tried below, but its putting a new key rather than replacing the existing once.even tried with putOnce()

```
jsonObjOriInj=new JSONObject(jsonobjectString);
jsonObjOriInj.put("emailRecipients", "2323");
```

Comment: You can find some useful help on the [ask] page to improve your question. A good asked question will help to understand your problem and increase the chance for a good answer.

Comment: You may have formatting / escape character issues in that JSON, particularly around `"{\"messageId\":\"232342",`. If this JSON is manually written, be sure to fix the formatting first.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I am able to put. but some formatting issue. Looking for help.  Its updating in below format
{"emailRecipients":"xyz@gmail.com"} .                                                                       Want it in below format {"emailRecipients":["test@abc.com"]}                                     Using below code: jsonObjOriginal.put("emailRecipients","xyz@gmail.com");Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, but assuming JSON should be in following format,

```
{
    "payload": {
        "injectedDetails": {
             "injectedDetails": "test"
        }
     },
     "originalPayload": {
        "messageId": "232342",
        "emailRecipients":[
            "test@abc.com"
        ]
     },
    "status": "OK"
}
```

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String data = "{\"payload\":{\"injectedDetails\":{\"injectedDetails\":\"test\"}},\"originalPayload\":{\"messageId\":\"232342\",\"emailRecipients\":[\"test@abc.com\"]},\"status\":\"OK\"}";

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);

        //get originalPayload object
        JSONObject originalPayload = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("originalPayload");

        // create new json array
        JSONArray newEmailRecipients = new JSONArray();

        // add new email recipients
        newEmailRecipients.add("updated_test@abc.com");

        // update originalPayload object with new emailRecipients
        originalPayload.put("emailRecipients", newEmailRecipients);

        // update JSON with updates originalPayload object
        jsonObject.put("originalPayload", originalPayload);

        System.out.println(jsonObject);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
{"payload":{"injectedDetails":{"injectedDetails":"test"}},"originalPayload":{"messageId":"232342","emailRecipients":"[updated_test@abc.com]"},"status":"OK"}
```